# File preview showing last selected file in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, file

I am trying to preview selected file in Angular 9.

```
<h3>Angular 9 Image Preview before Upload:</h3>
<input #file type="file" accept='image/*' (change)="preview(file.files)" />
<img [src]="imgURL" height="200" *ngIf="imgURL">
```

And ts file is

```
preview(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      let message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
      this.imgURL = _event.target.result; 
    }
  }
```

But when first time i select the file i dont get any display, next time when i upload a file i get the display of last file i selected. I saw many working example with the same concept on internet, Is there any change in file upload login for new angular version i.e Angular 9.

Comment: No there is no change your code is working . Can you put your code in stackblitz  ?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-caigap code is working

Answer (score 0):

After some RnD got the solution. We need to call detectChanges() after the imgUrl is changed.

```
preview(files) {
    if (files.length === 0)
      return;

    var mimeType = files[0].type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      let message = "Only images are supported.";
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); 
    reader.onload = (_event) => { 
    this.imgURL = _event.target.result; 
    this.ref.detectChanges();

    }
  }
```

the above solution worked fine for me.